# Generating javadoc for a java project

Tags: java, comments, javadoc

Recently we planned to use checkstyle plug-in in our project. As a part of this exercise existing code has to be cleaned up to comply with checkstyle rules. We have found that close to 18K violations correspond to absence of javadoc comments in class files.

My question is, is there any plugin or tool which i can use to generate javadoc comments for the entire artifacts?
I had a look at [JAutodoc](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/) , and I would 
like to know whether there is anything better than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your real code quality will go down by generating JavaDoc, even if the CheckStyle score goes up. Generated JavaDoc can only reflect what is already obvious from the code, it adds volume which decreases readability and it probably (depending on you tool) will not keep itself up to date, adding a maintenance burden and leading to inconsistencies after the code evolves.

Don't let yourself be badgered into cluttering your code. The CheckStyle violations should be taken as hints, not absolute iron-clad rules. Adding sensible JavaDoc takes time and understanding of the code, you should make policy for creating it from now on in all new code, and add it in any existing code when it gets refactored.

BTW: you don't have to JavaDoc everything. I personally don't JavDoc default getters/setters, overrides or methods/fields with self-explanatory names (which I strive for). I always JavaDoc top level entities (interfaces, classes and enums) and put non-JavaDoc comments on blocks of code that do something complicated.

Comment: Adrian, Thanks for the response. Personally even I have the same opinion. But our client wants to  add javadoc comments to the existing source code and modify the same when we refactor the code. Unfortunately client's opinion matter a lot in this case and we got lesser say in decision making.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a NetBeans project you can ask it to automatically generate the missing skeletons for you.  A simple right mouse click on the project to select the menu item and you will have all the missing skeletons in place.

Another tool (costs money, but well worth it) is the commercial version of [Jalopy from triemax](http://www.triemax.com/) which is an excellent code formatter (the developer is super responsive and adds new features relatively quickly when requested).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking at Jalopy. Will evaluate and recommend to the client if it fits our requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem recently. We just changed the checkstyle configuration file to set missing javadocs only as warnings until our contributors have included the missing docs.

How to do this is decribed here [link text](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html), or you can use the eclipse checkstyle plugin which provides a GUI interface.

Comment: Ali, adding 18000 javadoc comments manually for a code base looks like a herculean task. Our plan is to add generated javadoc now and modify the same when we modify the class/methods down the line.